# how to show and hide div based on the checkbox selection in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a checkbox built from an array.

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let plan of plans; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
        <label class="form-check-label fw7 h5 mb0">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox">
          {{plan.planShortName}}
        </label>
<div>
```

i need to show and hide a div in the end of the page if the plan.mailingResponsibility is true for any one of the selected plan. by default one of the plan is always selected when the page loads. Any guidance on this of how my approach should be? 
below is the div i need to show and hide

```
  <div *ngIf="showFootNote">
        <p>
          * By providing an e-mail address you agree to the terms..
        </p>
      </div>
```

Here is the sample that i am working on Sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnw2wg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: So you need to toggle `showFootNote` state by looking every checkbox change, right?

Comment: You have not bind the checkbox input to any variable. Why is that?

Comment: yes on the checkbox change .if two checkboxes are selected and one of it has the property mailResponsibility True I need to show the foot note. Also by default one checkbox is already selected when the page loads so i will have to check that one too. i did not bind the checkbox input because it wasnt necessary to get the value of it. I can add should nt be a problem

Comment: Check the below solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `showFootNote` should be false by default.

```
showFootNote: boolean = false;
```

You need to bind the checkbox input to some field. I have added a field `isChecked` in the `Plan` interface.

```
<label>
    <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        [(ngModel)]="plan.isChecked" 
        formControlName="checkbox" 
        (change)="updateState()">
    {{plan.planShortName}}
</label>
```

Use change event to call a function to update the state of `showFootNote`.

```
updateState(){
    // Reset 
    this.showFootNote = false;
    // Itearte over plans 
    this.plans.forEach(
        plan => {
            // If selected and flag is true
            if(plan.isChecked && plan.mailingResponsibility){
                this.showFootNote = true;
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzcsaw

Comment: This helps Thanks. But Also by default one checkbox is already selected when the page loads so how to check that one if the property is true or not?

Comment: Which one will be checked? The first one? Set its value while intializing plans.

Comment: Does this meet your requirement : [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzcsaw](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzcsaw)

Comment: All looks good except if the checkbox selected initially has `mailingResponsibility` true, the footnote won't be displayed since the event handler hasn't been triggered yet. To solve it, it can be triggered once in `ngOnInit()`. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-853wzd